# ¿Comó recibir los datos de FormData en un Servlet?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets

Buen día con todos estoy tratando de enviar un objeto FormData por Fetch a un Servlet pero al recibirlos me imprimen con el resultado de null, no me aparece ningún error solo que la respuesta al final me sale como null

```
window.onload = () => {
let frmPersona = document.querySelector("form");
frmPersona.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const objetoPersona = new FormData(e.target);
    fetch("ServletAjax",{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: objetoPersona
    }).then(res=>{
        return res.text();
    }).then(resultado=>{
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
    });
```

Y en mi Servlet recibo los datos por medio del atributo name de los inputs del form

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
        out.print(nombre + " " + apellido);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución al problema que presentaba en este enlace [html5-formdata-returns-null-in-java-servlet-request-getparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292382/html5-formdata-returns-null-in-java-servlet-request-getparameter) al parecer con FormData los datos se envían a través de fetch como `multipart/form-data` y como `request.getParameter` reconoce solicitudes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` se debe agregar en el Servlet la siguiente anotación `@MultipartConfig` para que de esta manera podamos obtener los datos con `request.getParameter`. Entonces el código en JavaScript quedaría así:

```
window.onload = () => {
let frmPersona = document.querySelector("form");
frmPersona.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const objetoPersona = new FormData(e.target);
fetch("ServletAjax",{
    method: "POST",
    body: objetoPersona
}).then(res=>{
    return res.text();
}).then(resultado=>{
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
});
```

Y en el Servlet tendría que agregar la anotación `@MultipartConfig` como se muestra a continuación

```
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet(name = "ServletAjax", urlPatterns = {"/ServletAjax"})
public class ServletAjax extends HttpServlet {
```

De esta manera los datos se enviarían de manera correcta y se mostrarían en pantallas al retornarlos.